# can't separate html elements

Tags: html, forms

Some reason, I'm having trouble separating a submit button from another drop down box/text. I just want to start a new line, but I can't seem to get it to work. sorry if it's vague. here's my code.

```
<br>
<span id ="p4">Grade Achieved?</span>



<select name = "classGrades" id ="classGradesx">
  <option value="A1" id ="A1">A+</option>
  <option value="A2" id ="A2">A</option>
  <option value="A3" id ="A3">A-</option>
  <option value="B1" id ="B1">B+</option>
  <option value="B2" id ="B2">B</option>
  <option value="B3" id ="B3">B-</option>
  <option value="C1" id ="C1">C+</option>
  <option value="C2" id ="C2">C</option>
  <option value="C3" id ="C3">C-</option>
  <option value="D1" id ="D1">D+</option>
  <option value="D2" id ="D2">D</option>
  <option value="D3" id ="D3">D-</option>
  <option value="F" id ="F">F</option>

<br/>

<input type="button" value="Add Class" id="addclassx" onClick="doStuff()">
<br>
```

Grade achieved, the dropdown box with the grades, and the Add Class submit button are all on the same line. I don't want the add class button on the same line. Thanks.

Comment: There's no `</select>`.  There should be one after all the options.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel really stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the select tag?

```
<br>
<span id ="p4">Grade Achieved?</span>



<select name = "classGrades" id ="classGradesx">
  <option value="A1" id ="A1">A+</option>
  <option value="A2" id ="A2">A</option>
  <option value="A3" id ="A3">A-</option>
  <option value="B1" id ="B1">B+</option>
  <option value="B2" id ="B2">B</option>
  <option value="B3" id ="B3">B-</option>
  <option value="C1" id ="C1">C+</option>
  <option value="C2" id ="C2">C</option>
  <option value="C3" id ="C3">C-</option>
  <option value="D1" id ="D1">D+</option>
  <option value="D2" id ="D2">D</option>
  <option value="D3" id ="D3">D-</option>
  <option value="F" id ="F">F</option>
</select>
<br/>

<input type="button" value="Add Class" id="addclassx" onClick="doStuff()">
<br>
```

Comment: You're a hero... How do I give credit?

Comment: Just use paypal ;) I take bitcoins too..